# When do i flag low-quality?

Tags: support, flagging

When a flag of mine gets rejected, it's usually a 'low quality' flag.

Can I get some clarification about how they work?

> [image]

I flagged an answer here, which was rejected - but then the answer was deleted by mods - presumably because it was low quality.

Below is a current answer which is live, which I feel is similar.

I think it's unarguably a bad answer. But I'm unsure, because it could be *salvaged* by editing, to be slightly better, but still bad.

> [image]

Personally, I think the low quality flag is being seen as a formatting flag - which taken to reporting-level is basically the same as a spam post, just not advertising.

What should I do in cases like this?

Comment: I think the problem was maybe you should have used the 'other' option so you could type in and explain why you were flagging the question/answer rather than using the default option reserved for completely unsalvagable questions/answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very low quality flags are reserved for post which **cannot be salvaged**.

The flag says:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Most (and by most I mean, 80%+) of the VLC flags I see can be salvaged by editing from the OP's (or even another community member's!) side.

Also, on the majority of said flags, a simple vote down is sufficient, if you feel fancy, leave a comment to OP and explain what's wrong and what he should add in an edit.

#### Examples:

> [in response to an [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request)...] The anime is Death Note

Downvote and comment "Please edit this question to include some more details, why do you think that this is Death Note? How does Death Note match OP's description?" etc.

> I like potatos

Doesn't relate to anything and should be removed. VLC applies nicely.

> I'm not sure, but your answer can be found on this awesome site that also sells potatoes!

That's SPAM. It's advertisment without disclosure.

Comment: is that not the same as spam though?

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko: No, SPAM implies that there's some sort of advertisement involved. I'll edit to add.

Comment: thanks :) I think I've cleared up it in my head now

Comment: "I like potatos" is not VLC, it's NAA. (Unless posted as a question.)